# QGIS Auto-update function/script

Tags: qgis

With the help of @Kazuhito, I have achieved a fine result in my valve and pipe simulation project. When I close a random valve, all flow in this direction is automatically closed and the color changes from green to red.

However, although I have set "default value on update", I have to run the update process manually in order to get it updated.

[image]

Is it possible to make an "action" with update function or a "script button" to make the task more elegant?

I haven't learned Pyton yet.

Comment: It seems `Default Field Value` currently fails to auto-update (reported by [csk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/297021/84455) for 3.2.2, and still persists in 3.4.3). Perhaps setting the **Virtual Field** is an option?

Comment: They are made as virtual fields

Comment: If it was a virtual field you wouldn't be able to update it that way. Virtual fields don't show up as options in the dropdown menu at the top-left corner of the attribute table.

Comment: you are right, it is the table to the right which is virtual and which is jojnt to the left ..... my mistake