# Exporting QGIS Field Calculator user defined function

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, export

I have created many Python functions in QGIS Field Calculator Function Editor. How can I export the user defined functions to use in other computers or share to other people?

My QGIS is 3.12.1 on MacOS 10.15.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving Equations used in QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296955/saving-equations-used-in-qgis-field-calculator)

Comment: @Nil no, not this. But thank you for editing my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user Python functions are stored within the profile directory of your active profile. Under Mac it should be something like *`~/Library/Application\Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles`*.

The easiest thing will be use Menu: `Settings->User Profiles->Open Active Profile Folder`. There you will find a folder *`/python/expressions`* where the Python functions are stored. You can copy the expressions folder or the Python scripts to other computer or profiles, then the functions will be available.

Comment: Yes, it is!  Exactly it is here: `~/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/expressions/`. But the problem with this is that if I uninstall QGIS, I lose the scripts

Comment: No, if you uninstall QGIS, the userprofiles will not be deleted - on windows, on Mac may be the same.